# How do you have if statements with a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following input file 'r1'

```
14 14
15 15
```

I would like to create the following output file 'r2'.

```
14 14 less than 15
15 15 equal to 15
```

I am trying to do so using the following code.

```
import numpy as np

s=open('r1')
r=open('r2','w+')

r1=np.loadtxt(s)
atim=r1[:,[0]]
alat=r1[:,[1]]

if atim<15 and alat<15:
    print >> r,atim,alat,'less than 15'

if atim==15 and alat==15:
    print >> r,atim,alat,'equal to 15'
```

However, when I run the program I get the following error
   if atim<15 and alat<15:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: That's a pretty good error message, did you try following up on the suggestions you got there?

Answer (score 1):

You want to do a comparison like

```
all(i < 15 for i in r1[0])
all(i == 15 for i in r1[0])
```

so you could do:

```
for row in len(r1):
    if all(i < 15 for i in r1[row]):
        print >> r,r1[row][0], r1[row][1], 'less than 15'
    if all(i == 15 for i in r1[row]):
        print >> r,r1[row][0], r1[row][1], 'equal to 15'
```

Answer (score 0):

with numpy, it's pretty easy:

```
[(a < 15).all() for a in r1]
```

or

```
[(a == 15).all() for a in r1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

r1 = np.array([[11, 15],
               [15, 15],
               [14, 14]])

equal_to_15 = (r1[:,0] == 15) & (r1[:,1] == 15)
less_than_15 = (r1[:,0] < 15) & (r1[:,1] < 15)
```

Result:

```
>>> equal_to_15
array([False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
>>> less_than_15
array([False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Error Message:

When you compare an array to integer you get a boolean array.

```
>>> np.array([13, 15]) == 15
array([False,  True], dtype=bool)
>>> if _:
...     print 'Hi'
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

And numpy does not evaluate the whole array for truthness, but if we did:

```
>>> if (np.array([13, 15]) == 15).any():
...     print 'Hi'
... 
Hi
```